# how Sub::Name set anonymous subroutine 's caller to NOT __ANON__?

Tags: perl

I reading programming perl, at chapter 12, the objects, has following documents :

The next::method has a similar problems because it uses the package of
its caller to figure out what class to look at. If you define a method
in Donkey from another package, next::method will break:

```
package main;
*Donkey::sound = sub { (shift)–>next::method(@_) };
```

The anonymous subroutine shows up in the stack with as _ *ANON* _, so next::method doesn’t know which package it is in. You can use the Sub::Name CPAN module to make it work out, though:

```
use Sub::Name qw(subname);
*Donkey::sound = subname 'Donkey::sound' => sub { (shift)–>next::method(@_) };
```

I am very inquisitive how Sub::Name module complete this work ? let the anonymous subroutine's caller not be __ANON__

very thanks your help :)

Comment: The source code is available [here](http://api.metacpan.org/source/FLORA/Sub-Name-0.05/Name.xs). It is in .xs format, which reads pretty much like C

Comment: yes, but why use .xs, although it is fast. or must use .xs to complete this ?

Answer (score 2):

From *inside* an anonymous subroutine you can achieve this by setting `*__ANON__` to the desired name:

```
$sub = sub {
    local *__ANON__ = 'Donkey::sound';
    ...
```

but Sub::Name sets it from the outside. A quick glance at the code leads me to think that it's poking and prodding the same stuff that setting `*__ANON__` does, and you can't do that from perl code. It's in XS because it has to be, not because it's faster that way.